How do I forward VLAN-tagged Ethernet frames through a Linux bridge between two physical Ethernet interfaces?
Background
I am currently working on a device that uses a Beaglebone Black as the base board, and has a 3rd-party MAC/PHY attached to the breakout pins.
Problem
The desire is to forward all Ethernet packets received on one interface to the other interface, in both directions. Configuring a bridge between the two interfaces is simple enough:
        ip link add name br0 type bridge
        ip link set dev br0 up
        ip link set eth0 up
        ip link set eth1 up
        ip link set dev eth0 master br0
        ip link set dev eth1 master br0

This works great until I start transmitting VLAN-tagged frames. If I tag the frame with VLAN ID 0 or 1, the frames are forwarded. Unfortunately, the VLAN tag is dropped before being transmitted on the other interface. If I tag with any other VLAN ID, the frame is not forwarded.
Solution Attempt 1
The first thing I tried was to use ebtables:
ebtables -A FORWARD -i br0 --vlan-id 2 -j ACCEPT
This didn't have any effect. Even if it did, it wouldn't scale very well -- I'd have to add an entry for all VLAN IDs I wish to use.
Solution Attempt 2
The second thing I tried was bridging sub-interfaces:
ip link add name br0.2 type bridge
ip link set dev br0.2 up
vconfig add eth0 1
vconfig add eth1 2
ip link set dev eth0.2 up
ip link set dev eth1.2 up
ip link set dev eth0.2 master br0.2
ip link set dev eth1.2 master br0.2

This works partially, but suffers from the same scaling problem as solution 1. I say it works partially, because the VLAN tag data is partially lost. Using tcpdump --x -i ethX, I observed the following when transmitting VLAN-tagged frames to the Beaglebone's onboard Ethernet interface (eth0):

When the packet arrives on eth0, the entire VLAN tag is present.
When the packet arrives on eth0.2, the VLAN tag has been stripped.
When the packet arrives on br0.2, the VLAN tag is still not present.
When the packet arrives on eth1.2, the VLAN tag is still not present.
When the packet arrives on eth1, a VLAN tag with the correct ID is present, but the priority has been lost.

Is there any way to preserve the entire VLAN tag as it passes through this chain of interfaces?
Solution Attempt 3
VLAN-aware bridge
ip link add name br0 type bridge vlan_filtering 1
ip link set dev br0 up
ip link set eth0 up
ip link set eth1 up
ip link set dev eth0 master br0
ip link set dev eth1 master br0
bridge vlan add vid 2-4094 dev br0 self
bridge vlan add vid 2-4094 dev eth0 master
bridge vlan add vid 2-4094 dev eth1 master

This would be a potentially ideal solution, since it doesn't suffer from the scaling problem of solution 2. However, the driver for the TI Ethernet switch fails to initialize when VLAN forwarding is enabled. The TI CPSW driver reports an error saying it is unable to initialize VLAN forwarding on the interface.

"If I tag the frame with VLAN ID 0 or 1".  VLAN ID 0 is not a valid tag.  0 and 4095 are "reserved".  The bridge you originally created should work (I do the same between wifi and ethernet).  Try with VLAN tags 10 and 11.

As stated later in the same paragraph, if I tag the frame with any other VLAN ID, the frame is not forwarded all the way through.

Does one of those Ethernet interfaces physically belong to a switch chip? Some of those use 802.1Q tags internally to direct packets to a specific port, so my initial guess is that you'd need to do double tagging... or figure out the cause behind the "unable to initialize VLAN" driver error.

@u1686_grawity The Beaglebone's AM335x SoC has an embedded 3-port switch. One port is internal, and the other two are externally facing. The Beaglebone only exposes one of the two external interfaces, and the device tree has the other one disabled.

@u1686_grawity I'm hesitant to blame the switch in solution attempt 2. The data path I'm examining is eth0-->eth0.2-->br0.2-->eth1.2-->eth1. eth0 is the the AM33x physical interface, and eth1 is the 3rd party MAC/PHY physical interface. The VLAN tag is being stripped between eth0 and eth0.2. This leads me to believe that something in the Linux network stack is stripping the VLAN tag.

@user25729276 The VLAN tag is being stripped between eth0 and eth0.2. But that's exactly how the dot1q (sub)interface suppose to work -- tagged frame ingress via its link (eth0) would get untagged when ingress via the interface, and untagged frames that egress via the interface (and in turn its link) would get tagged (before egressing via the link). I don't know why (or if it could in any case make sense to) you enslave the dot1q interfaces to the bridge, but it would be normal that what ingress the bridge via them would get untagged.

@user25729276 It might be possible to get the traffics tagged again by using bridge vlan add to set a pvid for the dot1q interfaces (now bridge slaves/ports), but it probably makes little to no sense to have such setup, and obviously you can only have one pvid for each of them.

@TomYan The frames do get tagged when leaving eth1.2. However, the priority is lost, since it was stripped when leaving eth0. My desire is for VLAN-tagged frames that enter eth0 to leave eth1 unmodified (same applies to frames entering eth1 and exiting eth0). The reason for this seemingly nonsensical setup is that the two physical interfaces are different physical layer standards, and thus I need to convert between the two.

It turns out the problem was with the default configuration of the embedded TI switch. The CPSW driver sets the ALE.CONTROL.VLAN_AWARE, CPSW_SS.CONTROL.VLAN_AWARE, CPSW_SS.CONTROL.RX_VLAN_ENCAP bits by default. By clearing these bits, all Ethernet frames, VLAN-tagged and otherwise, pass through unmodified.
With these changes, the solution outlined in the problem description works.
